# Overflow for background color of text

Tags: html, css, overflow, background-color

I applied background color to the links in my country list. It works well in general:

[image]

However, for the countries which have longer name, it doesn't work very well.

[image]

I'm trying to make the yellow color overflow everything and show country's full name clearly.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="flagList">
<div class="flagColumn"> ... </div>
<div class="flagColumn"> ... </div>
<div class="flagColumn"> ... </div>
...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flagColumn {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    border:0px solid;
    height:1.6em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    z-index: 1; position:relative;
}

.flagColumn:hover {
   overflow:visible;
   z-index: 2; position:relative;
   display: inline;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use HTML tables. They will properly format the rows and columns. Tables will be well formatted too.
Check this tutorial to get started: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the content of `.flagColumn` in an extra element, setting it to `display: inline-block;` and setting the background on that instead:

```css
.flagColumn {
    float: left;
    height: 1.6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.flagColumn:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.flagColumn:hover span {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flagList">
    <div class="flagColumn"><span>This is test text!</span></div>
    <div class="flagColumn"><span>This is a lot longer test text! This is a lot longer test text!</span></div>
    <div class="flagColumn"><span>This is a lot longer test text! This is a lot longer test text!</span></div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hL9qfuvb/1/